# Compiling of SQlite3 in C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, compilation, g++

I compile code this way:

```
g++ main.cpp -I sqlite3
```

where sqlite3 is a folder with source files which I received from sqlite-amalgamation-3071100.zip, -I is flag for including sources.

This archive contains : shell.c, sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3ext.h.

This is what I receive:

```
undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
```

The program just contain #include  and call of function sqlite3_open(...);

---

I can compile all fine if I make "sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev" and compile program with command

```
g++ main.cpp -lsqlite3
```

But I want to solve that problem, because I do not want to have to install some libraries on another computer, I do not have access for that!

Comment: You need to build the library and then link against it.

Comment: Why do you think you'll be able to link against the libsqlite3 library when it's not installed?

Comment: Kerrek SB, you see that library contains just 4 files. How to build it and what I need when I have sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files.  Do I need to make "g++ -o sqlite3 sqlite3.h sqlite3.c" ???  I just try to compile it with "g++ -o myprog myprog.cpp sqlite3.c sqlite3.h"  But I receive a lot of errors.

Comment: What are you trying to build - sqlite3 command line clien or the sqlite3 library?

Answer (score 16):

- Step1: compile sqlite3.c to **sqlite3.o** by gcc
- Step2: compile your c++ code together with **sqlite3.o** by g++

My makefile for sqlite shell and c++ api test:

```
  1 CXX = g++
  2 cc = gcc
  3 
  4 LIB = -lpthread -ldl
  5 BIN = sqlite apiTest
  6 
  7 all : $(BIN)
  8 sqlite : sqlite3.c shell.c
  9     $(cc) -o $@ $^ $(LIB) 
 10 apiTest : apiTest.cpp sqlite3.o
 11     $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIB) 
 12 sqlite3.o : sqlite3.c
 13     $(cc) -o $@ -c $^
 14 
 15 clean :
 16     rm -f $(BIN)
 17 
 18 .PHONY: all, clean
```

Answer (score 5):

Download the sqlite amalgamation from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html.

1. Include any reference to sqlite as extern "C", since sqlite is written in C.
2. Create the sqlite library with "gcc -c sqlite3.c".
3. Link your program to the newly created library with "g++ main.c sqlite3.o"

Comment: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘Table*’ and so on!!! 100 lines.  "g++ main.cpp sqlite3.c"   There is not sqlite3.cpp exist.

Comment: You need to compile `sqlite3.c` with a C compiler (`gcc`).

Comment: sqlite3 is written in C, not C++.  You'll need to compile it with `gcc`, not `g++`.  And you may need to use `extern "C"` in your C++ code.

Comment: Download the sqlite3 souce code from the provided link. You will see a file called "sqlite3.c", which you need to supply to g++ when compiling.

Comment: sqlite3 compiles fine with C++ code and g++. You just need to use extern "C" in your includes.

Comment: @AsierGutierrez: That's incorrect. The C code in `sqlite3.c` is not compatible with C++ (remember that C++ is not a strict superset of C). You need to compile `sqlite3.c` with a C compiler; once you've done that, you can link it with C++ code.  `sqlite3.h` already has a conditional `extern "C"`, so that part is taken care of.

Comment: OK, yeap, my bad. It worked for me in the past, but it looks like there is a bug with g++. So, you should create the library first (gcc -c sqlite3.c) and then link it with your program (g++ main.cpp sqlite3.o)

Answer (score 2):

You *will* need to compile `sqlite3` with `gcc`. I tried `g++` and the result was hundreds of errors and warnings.

Perhaps `sqlite3` shoule be written in such a way that it would compile with a C++ compiler. C++ compilers are much choosier and enforce types and such much better than a C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu:

gcc -o test test.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -idl

1. I declared #include "sqlite3.h" in source file (test.c) #include  did NOT work.
2. gcc -o test test.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -idl

The reference as stated below:

https://www.sqlite.org/draft/howtocompile.html

Answer (score 0):

On Windows with MinGW32 compile a dynamic link library by:

```
gcc -shared sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.dll
```